# Find the sum $\sum_{r=1}^n (r(r+1))^2 (-1)^r$ in terms of n.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, telescopic-series

Find the sum $$\sum_{r=1}^n (r(r+1))^2  (-1)^r$$ in terms of n.

**My approach**

I tried to make telescoping terms by adding another a constant term written in terms of r, $((r+2)-(r-1))$ but the $(-1)^r$ wouldn't allow them to cancelled.

Comment: Let us denote this expression by $S_n$. You can compute $S_{2n}$ by grouping the terms pairwise. If my computation is correct you will get $8n^2(n+1)^2$. Then compute $S_{2n+1}$ and try to merge the two formulas into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $n$ is even
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^n(r(r+1))^2(-1)^r&=\sum_{r=1}^{n/2}((2r+1)2r)^2-((2r-1)2r)^2\\
&=32\sum_{r=1}^{n/2}r^3\\
&=32(\frac{n^2}{8}+\frac{n}4)^2\\
&=n^2(n+2)^2/2,
\end{align*}$$
using the classic formula $\sum_{i=1}^mi^3=(m(m+1)/2)^2$. Similarly if $n$ is odd
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{r=1}^n(r(r+1))^2(-1)^r&=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(r(r+1))^2(-1)^r-(n(n+1))^2\\
&=(n-1)^2(2n-1)^2/2-n^2(n+1)^2\\
&=\frac12(2n^4-16n^3+11n^2-6n+1).
\end{align*}$$

Comment: could you explain what you did in the first step where you reduced the summation up till $n/2$ terms

Comment: It's by combining the terms $r=2k$ and $r=2k+1$

Comment: I figured that, I wanted to know how the term $-((2r-1)2r)^2$ appeared

Comment: Because I combine $r=2k-1$ and $r=2k$ for $r=1,\dots,n/2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider instead $$\sum_{r=1}^n (r(r+1))^2 x^r$$ and write

$$(r(r+1))^2=r(r-1)(r-2)(r-3)+8r(r-1)(r-2)+14r(r-1)+4r$$ to face derivatives of well know summations.

When done, let $x=-1$.